# Cache() in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe and I need to include several transformations on it. I thought of performing all the actions in the same dataframe. So if I need to use cache Should I cache the dataframe after every action performed in it ?

```
df=df.selectExpr("*","explode(area)").select("*","col.*").drop(*['col','area'])
df.cache()
df=df.withColumn('full_name',f.concat(f.col('first_name'),f.lit(' '),f.col('last_name'))).drop('first_name','last_name')
df.cache()
df=df.withColumn("cleaned_map", regexp_replace("date", "[^0-9T]", "")).withColumn("date_type", to_date("cleaned_map", "ddMMyyyy")).drop('date','cleaned_map')
df.cache()
df=df.filter(df.date_type.isNotNull())
df.show()
```

Should I add like this or caching once is enough ?

Also I want to know if I use multiple dataframes instead of one for the above code should I include cache at every transformation. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simple, when you do `df = df.cache()` or `df.cache()` both are locates to an RDD in the granular level. Now , once you are performing any operation the it will create a new RDD, so this is pretty evident that will not be cached, so having said that it's up to you which DF/RDD you want to `cache()`.Also, try avoiding try unnecessary caching as the data will be persisted in memory.

Below is the source code for `cache()` from spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd-pysrc.html#RDD.cache)

```
def cache(self): 
    """ 
    Persist this RDD with the default storage level (C{MEMORY_ONLY_SER}). 
    """ 
    self.is_cached = True 
    self.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER) 
    return self
```

Comment: Seems like caching removes the distributed put of computing and might make queries much slower.  I am trying to figure out how to speed things up and caching might be going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Absolutely, it's very dangerous for the use cases too wherein the data is huge!